# C++: Devirtualize Leaf Classes

Tags: c++, performance, oop, virtual-functions

In languages like Java, C# and D, `final` or `sealed` classes are guaranteed to be leaf classes (classes that no other class inherits from).  This allows the compiler top devirtualize method calls to objects whose compile-time type is `final` or `sealed`.

C++ does not have a `final` or `sealed` keyword.  Is there any way to simulate its behavior with regard to de-virtualization of classes that are leafs in my inheritance hierarchy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++11 does have [`final`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final), although it is a *special identifier*, not a keyword. It does not serve a "devirtualization" purpose. It simply prevents classes being derived from or single methods being overriden in derived classes.

Comment: Of course the standard isn't going to say anything about de-virtualization since vtables aren't even part of the standard, but any decent optimizer should do it anyhow.

Comment: BTW, I just confirmed by reading the disassembly that Clang does de-virtualize calls when `final` is used.

Comment: @dsimcha exactly, the compiler only has to follow the "as-if" rule.

Comment: My point is that in any reasonable implementation, `final` will serve a devirtualization purpose even if technically the standard doesn't require it.

Comment: @dsimcha Yes, I get your point and I agree. `final` provides the compiler with more information to make these optimizations.

Comment: I confirm that also the latest version of GCC is able to de-virtualize function calls to final methods.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do such a thing in C++ is to make sure that the compiler know the static and dynamic types are the same and let the optimizer realize the virtual call isn't needed. In other words, access the object by value and not through a reference or pointer. This even works on *non*-leaf types!